# Header image automatically changes depending on season

Tags: filters, css

For days trying to figure out what is wrong with script. As a theme using 'primer'. Point is to make header image change by itself for each season. At page header appears `fall` and thats it, even when im testing different months for different seasons, nothing happens. Maybe somebody can help me solve this issue.

funcion

```
    add_filter('masthead','site-header');
function seasonal_site_header ($classes = '') {
   $hemisphere = 'northern';
   $m = date('m');
    
   $northern=array(
     'summer' => array(6, 7, 8),
     'fall' => array(9, 10, 11),
     'winter' => array(12, 1, 2),
     'spring' => array(3, 4, 5)
   );

   foreach($$hemisphere as $key=>$val) {
     if(in_array($m, $val)) {
       $classes[] = $key;
       return $classes;
     }
   }
   $classes[] = '';
   return $classes;
}
```

css

```
#masthead, .site-header, .winter
{
  background-image: url('/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/winter.jpg');

}
#masthead, .site-header, .spring
{
  background-image: url('/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/spring.jpeg');

}
#masthead, .site-header, .summer #site-header-wrapper
{
  background-image: url('/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/summer.jpeg');

}
#masthead, .site-header, .fall
{
  background-image: url('/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/autumn.jpg');

}
```

Comment: What is the first line doing? Do you have a hook called `masthead`? Even if you do, `site-header` is not a valid callback.

Answer (score 0):

Change filter call

```
add_filter('masthead','seasonal_site_header', 10, 2);

function seasonal_site_header ($classes = '') {
   $hemisphere = 'northern';
   $m = date('m');
    
   $northern=array(
     'summer' => array(6, 7, 8),
     'fall' => array(9, 10, 11),
     'winter' => array(12, 1, 2),
     'spring' => array(3, 4, 5)
   );

   foreach($$hemisphere as $key=>$val) {
     if(in_array($m, $val)) {
       $classes[] = $key;
       return $classes;
     }
   }
   return $classes;
}
```

Change css

```
#masthead.site-header.winter
{
  background-image: url('/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/winter.jpg');

}
#masthead.site-header.spring
{
  background-image: url('/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/spring.jpeg');

}
#masthead.site-header.summer
{
  background-image: url('/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/summer.jpeg');

}
#masthead.site-header.fall
{
  background-image: url('/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/autumn.jpg');

}
```